# Use Address Book for search firstname when receive notification on iphone app

Tags: iphone, contacts, apple-push-notifications

I spend some days to search solution about this trouble :
I have an app wich receive notificaiton from other user. The single data, I have under server side is the number phone. So I want, when the notification is receive on the iphone, to link the number phone of sender to the addressbook of receiver for display, if the number phone is foud, the firstname of the sender to the notification.

This feature is like sms reception on the iphone, where is just the number phone used finally, and is linked to the address book.

The notification system on my app is enabled and run without trouble, but this feature is not resolved, and i found the response nowhere on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i search more, and i think, this feature could be possible if the app can write under the Localize.string. In fact, it could be possible to write key value, like ("93019320"="Carla") and in the notification text the phone number "93019320" is replace by the string "Carla". But the second question is
Is it possible to write in Localiza.string under app?